# android main layout and categories howto

Tags: android

in main layout i would like to use something like

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:summary="@string/menu_language_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_language_settings" >
```

but here i only have

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="50dp" >
```

how can i use Categories in main layout? Is this even possible in main layout?

Comment: lock at this sample http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/

Comment: preferences don't go in layout. they go in xml. you can use preferenceactivity or expandablelistview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use categories in Main layout xml like the following sample xml code:-

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/audio_quality" android:key="audio_quality">

       <EditTextPreference android:title="@string/echo_cancellation_tail"   android:key="echo_cancellation_tail" android:summary="@string/echo_cancellation_tail_desc" android:defaultValue="200" android:numeric="signed" /> 

       <ListPreference android:title="@string/echo_mode" android:key="echo_mode" android:summary="@string/echo_mode_desc" android:defaultValue="2" android:entryValues="@array/echo_mode_values" android:entries="@array/echo_mode_choices" /> 

     </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

otherwise create one xml folder in res and create new xml for catogeries

Answer (score 0):

`PreferenceCategory` is supposed to use for `PreferenceActivity` and is defined inside the **/res/xml** folder. I don't think you can define it in your layout's xml.